# Python 3 ConfigParser reading the inline comments as well

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, config, configparser

I have the following code, where the `filePath` is the path to a cfg file on disk. When I parse it, it also reads the inline comments (the ones with space + `";"`).

Some lines of the result:

xlsx:Yes                                                 ; comment goes here

html:Yes                                                 ; comment goes here

It should be:

xlsx:Yes

html:Yes

```
def ParseFile(filePath):
    """this function returns the parsed CFG file"""
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    print("Reading config file from %s" % filePath)
    parser.read(filePath)
    for section in parser.sections():
        print("[ SECTION: %s ]" % section)
        for option in parser.options(section):
            print("%s:%s" % (option, parser.get(section, option)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Inline comments are not enabled by default**.

From an example in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html):

```
[You can use comments]
# like this
; or this

# By default only in an empty line.
# Inline comments can be harmful because they prevent users
# from using the delimiting characters as parts of values.
# That being said, this can be customized.
```

To allow inline comments with `';'`:

```
parser = configparser.ConfigParser(inline_comment_prefixes=';')
```